# BTF: .tmp_vmlinux.btf: pahole version v1.15 is too old, need at least v1.16

Tags: software-installation, kernel, compiling

When I try make to the mainline (staging-test) kernel it ends up with the error

```
BTF: .tmp_vmlinux.btf: pahole version v1.15 is too old, need at least v1.16\
Failed to generate BTF for vmlinux\
Try to disable CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_BTF
make: *** [Makefile:1162: vmlinux] Error 1
```

So, when I google it I found that to install dwarves.
And when I install it, it showing its already there and that's the newer version which is V1.15-2. so its not upgrading to V1.16+, but the recent release is V1.18+

Here is my distro and kernel versions,

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release: 20.04
Codename: focal

Linux 5.9.0-050900rc7-generic x86_64 GNU/Linux

How can I resolve this?

Comment: To make mainline kernel it needs pahole V1. 16+, but ubuntu is still using v1. 15. So my question is "How to install pahole-v1.16+ ?" I'm not able to find any .deb file for that.

Comment: `pahole-v1.16+` may want something else newer versions and so on ;-)

Comment: I don't know Is this happen only for me or everyone? because lot of people will upgrade there kernel to mainline version right are they didn't face any such issues?

Comment: It is not true that " a lot of people are using mainline kernels". They are not supported and you are using it at your own risk. Problems are expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for your response I have got the .deb file for dwarvesV1.17 and pahole is upgrade to V1.17.
Here is link for that http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/d/dwarves-dfsg/dwarves_1.17-1_amd64.deb

Answer (score 0):

Hey I'm new to this and found a way to get past the pahole error stuff.

Anyways after some experimenting, looks like dwarves was removed from elfutils for some reason, and thus so was pahole. To get it, go here:

https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libdwarves&submit=Search+...

And download the correct version or grab the link and use it in wget like below. Why doesn't yum find dwarves I'm not sure.

```
wget https://rpmfind.net/linux/fedora/linux/development/rawhide/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/l/libdwarves1-1.17-4.fc34.x86_64.rpm
yes | sudo yum install libdwarves1-1.17-4.fc34.x86_64.rpm

wget https://rpmfind.net/linux/fedora/linux/development/rawhide/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/d/dwarves-1.17-4.fc34.x86_64.rpm
yes | sudo yum install dwarves-1.17-4.fc34.x86_64.rpm`
```

After doing this and running `pahole --version` I get v1.17

BTW I still get "failed to encode BTF" errors, but the kernel compiles successfully and I can boot into it after the next installation steps. That was last night with kernel v5.8.13

Now my problem is failed "load btf from vmlinux" which is probably in the same vein here. I did not get this error on 5.8.13 and now I can't install 5.8.14

Good luck.

Comment: this isn't going to work on Ubuntu though - we can't safely use `yum`